# Typescript Vuejs : Type 'Users[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ArrayConstructor': isArray, prototype, from, of, [Symbol.species]

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, supabase

I'm starting typescript with vuejs and I've just come across this error that I've been stuck on for 2 days.
The error is as follows: `Type 'Users[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ArrayConstructor': isArray, prototype, from, of, [Symbol.species]`

And here is my `GetAll.controller.ts` code:

```js
import { supabase } from "../server";

type Users = {
    user_id: Number,
    user_username: String,
    user_email: String,
    user_password: String,
    user_token: String
}

export async function GetAll():Promise<Users[]> {
    console.log('go');
    
    try {

        let { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('users')
            .select('*')
        if (error) throw error
        if (data) {
            return data
        } else {
            throw data
        }

    } catch (err) { throw(err); }
}
```

---

And my `App.vue`:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import {GetAll} from './API/GetAll.controller';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data(){
    return {
      users: Array
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.users = await GetAll()
  }
}
</script>
```

The error is below the `this.users` inside the `mounted()`

Comment: You're confusing TS types and JS runtime code. `{
      users: Array
    }` is the latter. Don't use options api for TS

Comment: I suspect that, you need to provide type to users as `Users[]`  inside `data()` property. 
Have you tried that?

Comment: You should do something like `users: [] as Array<any>` or `users: [] as Array<Users>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you so much, it solved, here is the answer :

```
<script lang="ts">
import {GetAll, Users} from './API/GetAll.controller';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data(){
     return {
      users: [] as Users[]
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.users = await GetAll()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your users the correct init value, if you don't define the type about users, typescript will treat your init value you assign be the default variable type.

```
...
  data(){
     return {
      users: [] as Users[]
    }
  }
...
```